# Shell script if condition

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I'm writing a script which runs the following command

```
mysql -u root -e "show databases"
```

and this will display a list of databases.

If this table doesn't contain a database by name "**userdb**", it should do the following-

```
if [ ... ]; then
 echo "error"
 exit
fi
```

What do i write in the **`if [ ... ]`** condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with `grep` if the table name is listed. `grep -q` will not print anything to the console but will set the exit status according to the result (the exit status will then be checked by `if`).

```
if ! mysql -u root -e 'show databases' | grep -q '^userdb$' ; then
    echo error
    exit
fi
```

About the regular expression: '`^`' matches the beginning of the line and '`$`' matches the end of the line (to avoid a false positive for database names containing `userdb`, e.g. `userdb2`)

Comment: or just `mysql -u root -e "show databases" |grep -q '^userdb$' && echo error && exit`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
usedb=DBname    
check=`mysql -u root -e "show databases" | grep $userdb`
if [ "$check" != "$userdb" ]; then
 echo "error"
exit
fi
```

But here will be an error if line with database name contain any other information.
Try to workaround it with `regexp`